# Is there any solution to resolve my input problem?

Tags: html, input

Hello I would like to solve this problem, when my input is not in my form and I press enter, the google search is performed but when it is in it does not work, no redirection made

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Bonjour, ---.</legend>
    <div class="inner-form">
      <div class="input-field">
        <button class="btn-search" type="button">
          <i class="fab fa-google fa-1x"></i>
        </button>

        <input id="textbox" type="text"
          placeholder="Rechercher sur Google..."
          onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) { location='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encdeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);}"
        />

      </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
      a:link {
        text-decoration: none
      }
    </style>
    <div class="suggestion-wrap">
      <a href="https://youtube.com"><span>YouTube</span></a>
      <a href="https://netflix.com"><span>Netflix</span></a>
      <a href="https://www.zara.com/fr/"><span>ZARA</span></a>
      <a href="https://www.apple.com/"><span>Apple</span></a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of doing a keydown, why not use the form how it's meant to be used and set the action and method attributes - read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Just as @Pete has said, it would be better to use a `<form>` tag instead of a `keydown` event. It would simplify your code much more and would allow for easier identification of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting enter within a form submits the form. Your form doesn't have an action attribute, so submitting the form will just reload the page.

You don't actually need any javascript to do a google search. Just set the input's name to 'q' and the form's action to 'https://google.com/search' and the let the form do what forms were made for.

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Rechercher sur Google..." />
</form>
```

---

If, for whatever reason, it's important that you do this with javascript instead of a regular form submission, you need to prevent the default action of the keydown event so the form doesn't submit:

```js
if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
   location='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encdeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);
}
```